# How to change the brush size in java

Tags: java

My class implements ChangeListener. I make a slider so I can change the size of the brush, and I have a variable called brush_size, but I don't know how can I change the brush_size in the stateChanged method.
Here is my code:

```
public class PaintBrushTool implements Tool, ChangeListener {

    private PaintBrushToolUI ui;
    private ImageEditorModel model;
    private int brush_size = 5;
    private JSlider sizeSlider;   // new slider

    public PaintBrushTool(ImageEditorModel model) {
        this.model = model;
        ui = new PaintBrushToolUI();

        JSlider sizeSlider = new JSlider();      // initialize the slide
        sizeSlider.addChangeListener(this);      // make this class listen to the PaintBrushToolUI class
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        model.paintAt(e.getX(), e.getY(), ui.getBrushColor(), brush_size);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        model.paintAt(e.getX(), e.getY(), ui.getBrushColor(), brush_size);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Paint Brush";
    }

    @Override
    public JPanel getUI() {
        return ui;
    }
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        // what should i put in here?
    }

}
```

Comment: Well for example..... 

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        brush_size++;
    }

Comment: @Blaatz0r: too simple. The slider can increase **and** decrease in value, and that value is usually not just by +1.

Comment: I love too simple answers

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the brushSize variable be held by the model? Regardless, simply get the value from the JSlider within the ChangeListener, by calling `getValue()` on it, and use this to set the brush size variable. If it's held by the model then call `setBrushSize(value)` on the model after getting the value from the JSlider, and be sure to give your model that method.

Your code appears to be using a M-V-C or Model-Viewer-Controller type structure. If so, then calling the model's setter method should trigger notification of model observers which will ultimately change the view.

Comment: Should I have a nested for loop?

Comment: @user6428015: Why? I don't see where you'd use that -- please explain. What array or collection (your code shows none) would you loop through?

Comment: Sorry to apply you late. So now I have the getValue(), and I set the brush size to the variable. But it is still not work. Here is my code: public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
  JSlider source = (JSlider)e.getSource();
  int sizeValue = source.getValue();
  brush_size = sizeValue;
 }

Comment: @user6428015: Please avoid showing code like that in comments. It cannot be formatted and is hard to read. Having said that, your code looks correct, in that it now appears to be setting the brush_size variable (which should be renamed `brushSize` to conform to Java camel case naming practices), but you will need to do some debugging to figure out why it's not behaving as you want, and this is only something you can do, since you have the entire program, and we don't (and we don't want it either).

Comment: @user6428015: Questions to ask: are you adding the ChangeListener to the JSlider? Is this JSlider the JSlider that is present in the GUI? How does the GUI use the brush_size variable data? Here is where it is probably better to put the value into the *model*.

Comment: How to add the ChangeListener to the JSlider? I think this is my problem now. When I try to print out the brushSize value, I did not get anything. So I think this is why my code is not work.

Comment: @user6428015: Not trying to be trivial, but surely you've tried `mySlider.addChangeListener(...)` type of code, right? But other issues about this code also doesn't sit right with me, since it looks to be controller code, not GUI code. Do you have other code for the GUI? If so, shouldn't the JSlider be in that code and not in this class? How have you designed this program? You may wish to improve this question showing more details of your program set up.

Comment: I have a class called PaintBrushToolUI class which contains the sizeSlider and Jpanel, JLabel and so on. In PaintBrushTool class, I make it listen to the UI class. And I tried myslider.addChangeListener, but it is not work.